# How to prove the equation $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{j} \frac{\binom{j}{k}\binom{D-j}{k}(-1)^k}{\binom{D/2}{k}}=\frac{(-1)^j(D-2j)}{D}.$

Tags: binomial-coefficients, hypergeometric-function

Let $D$ be an odd number. Let $j$ be an integer with $0\leq j\leq {\frac{D-1}{2}}$. I found the following equation on Wolfram-alpha:
$$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{j} \frac{\binom{j}{k}\binom{D-j}{k}(-1)^k}{\binom{D/2}{k}}=\frac{(-1)^j(D-2j)}{D}.$$

But I don't know how to prove it. Can anyone help me?

Comment: If $D=2m+1$, this series can be written as a hypergeometric one: $~_2F_1[-j,-1+j-2m,-1/2-m;1]$ which ten simplifies to $ (-1)^j (1-2j+2m)/(1+2m).$

Comment: @ZAhmed Thanks for the comment! Could you give some detail about the simplification or reference? Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $D=2m+1$, then due to the Hypergeometric series  $~_2F_1[a,b,c,z]$ see
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function

$$S=\sum_{k=0}^{j} (-1)^k\frac{{j \choose k} {2m+1-j \choose k}}{{m+1/2 \choose k}}=~_2F_1[-j,-1-j-2m,-1/2-m;1].$$
Further $~_2F_1[a,b,c;1]=\frac{\Gamma(c) \Gamma(c-a-b)}{\Gamma[c-a) \Gamma(c-b)}$, we get
$$S=\frac{\Gamma(-(1/2+m))~ \Gamma(1/2+m)}{\Gamma(-(1/2+m-j))~\Gamma(1/2+m-j)}.$$
Using $\Gamma(-z)\Gamma(z)=\frac{-\pi}{z \sin \pi z}$ see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function, we get
$$S=\frac{-\pi(1/2+m-j)\csc((1/2+m-j)\pi)}{-\pi(1/2+m)\csc((m+1/2)\pi)}, ~~~\sin((k+1/2)\pi)=(-1)^k.$$
So we get $$S=(-1)^j \frac{D-2j}{D}.
$$